# Replacing old server with new but different hostname & same IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, cname-record

We have an old server 2000 and lots of users point to it by hostname and by its IP e.g `\\server1`, we have a new server 2008 R2 with new name `serverlocation1`

All folders and data have been sync'toy'd from the old server1 across to serverlocation1 each evening, the new server tree is exactly the same on the new server and all perms are correct.

We need to make the new server the same IP as the old server1 as too many people access it directly via IP, and to ensure file and folder paths stay ok, anything `\\server1\folder\file` needs to go to `\\newserverlocation1\folder\file` etc

I can change the old `server1` name to `server1-old` & change IP and assign the old IP to the new server, but how do I force anything coming in for `\\server1` to go to the new server and ensure anything referenced to the old server goes onto the new server ?

I can CNAME but I need the new server to have the IP of the previous server so not sure if its straight forward etc.....

point `server1` to `newserverlocation1`
Then probably change DNS so that the OLD IP points to new hostname.....

Any clarification appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "*anything coming in for `\\server1` to go to the new server*"? You've changed the name and the IP address of the new server to match the old server - there is nothing more to it. Do you have other services than the file service on `server1`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop using the old server
2. Copy the data from the old server to the new server
3. Make sure that the shares and permissions on the new server match the old server
4. Shut down the old server
5. Rename the new server to the old server name and assign it the old server ip address
6. Done

Comment: If you want to use serverlocation1 from now on, do everything joeqwerty said just instead of 5. keep the new hostname and the previous IP on the 2008r2 and make sure the DNS server your users using have 2 records pointing to this IP. Dynamic with serverlocation1 and static with server1. The reverse record should be serverlocation1.